# Extracting Specific Numbers from Text Data

Tags: python, string, pandas, if-statement, int

I am working on an unsupervised machine learning algorithm studying marijuana data to offer suggestions on similar strains. I've run into a slight roadblock, which is that the CBD to THC ratio, which is a super import data point, is hidden within the 'Description' column with no real consistency on how it is phrased. Sometimes its 'X:Y CBD/THC ratio', sometimes it's 'a THC to CBD ratio of about X:Y', and sometimes other words are thrown in there to make it more confusing from a coding standpoint.

My current strategy is to make an if statement that searches through all of the descriptions to extract the data, but I can't figure out how to make it work. This is the base idea I'm working with.

```
strain_breakdown['THC/CBD Ratio'] = 0

for s in strain_data:
    if strain_data['Description'].str.contains(f'THC:CBD ratio of about {int}:{int}'):
        strain_breakdown['THC/CBD Ratio'] = int/int
```

Obviously, the code above doesn't work, but I'm trying to find something like this that might.

My plan is to follow this with elif statements that reference other ways that it is phrased in different descriptions and to make separate columns and if statements for THC to CBD ratios and CBD to THC ratios, bu to just need to find a way to extract the numbers. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Please add data example that we can use to try a solution and suggest it to you.

Comment: 'X:Y CBD/THC ratio' and  'a THC to CBD ratio of about X:Y' were the exmples, but here's a longer one.

'Argyle is a variety of Nordle grown by Canadian LP Tweed, Inc. The indica-dominant hybrid crosses Afghani and Sensi Star genetics. The resulting buds smell of garlic and herbs, like fresh cut chives but with a fruity aftertaste. With a 1:1 ratio of THC to CBD Argyle creates a mellow, calming buzz that is a great answer to body pains and muscle spasms.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "extract" function with a regex containing named groups like this :

```py
df = strain_data.Description.str.extract(r'THC:CBD ratio of about (?P<THC>[\d+]):(?P<CBD>[\d+])') # it returns a dataframe with two columns named "THC" and "CBD" with the values of THC and CBD if found in the description or with NaN if not found

strain_breakdown['THC/CBD Ratio'] = df.THC / df.CBD
```

You can work on the regex to avoid the elif statements that you were planning to do after.